# how to load different xml file in orientation change in android

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

can anybody tell how to load different xml file whenever user changes device orientation in android?

For example, I am using a profile screen in my application. In portrait mode, user gives 'user name' value, after that I change orientation to landscape, now I have to load different xml, so that user gives value in landsacpe mode.

Is it possible?

Thanks

**Editor's Note**: English doesn't seem to be his first language.

Comment: Please format your question properly, try using punctuation marks, it's impossible to understand your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create two types of layout directories to handle orientation . `layout-land` `layout-port`
put the xml with the same name in both the directory. if i have main.xml file then i have to put it in both directory.

Thanks

Comment: kumar which main file it will load in android

Comment: i have only named it as main.xml instead of that you have to use your xml

Answer (score 1):

Provide a different layout in layout-land\
See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. If the user has changed the orientation then you can set different XML on setContentView(R.id.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnConfigChange Method so when ever orientation change at that time this method will call autmatically and setContentView(R..id.nameofxml) from layout-land folder.